# Initializing a property of UIViewController from UITabBar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I need to set a property of the ViewController when clicked from the TabBar.

I tried doing it in `didSelectViewController` - but it is called after `ViewWillAppear` is done and it's too late

I tried doing it in:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

but the `viewController` is of the originating tabBarIndex and not the destination tabBarIndex

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well after digging in the code, I found a way:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
    if ([[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[DestinationViewController class]])
    {
        DestinationViewController *vc = (DestinationViewController *)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        vc.foo = 1;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `shouldSelect...` was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, you can set segue ID and then:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:YOUR_SEGUE_ID]) {
        YourViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```